# How to handle .json fine in tabular form in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

By using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
patients_df = pd.read_json('/content/students.json',lines=True)
patients_df.head()
```

the data are shown in tabular form look like this:
[image]

The main json file looks like this:

```
data = []
for line in open('/content/students.json', 'r'):
    data.append(json.loads(line))
```

[image]

How can I get the score column of the table in an organized manner like column name **Exam, Quiz, and Homework**

Comment: You might want to use `pd.json_normalize()`.

Comment: @quasi-human I tried many ways but every time I keep getting this error, for the code you save suggested the result is same: https://ibb.co/2W06RKB

Comment: Can you provide the content of `/content/students.json` as text?

Comment: yes, @quasi-human Use this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Akashkunwar/Guvi-assignment/main/Files%20of%20Student%20Database/students.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution could be the following:

```
# pip install pandas

import pandas as pd
import json


def separate_column(row):
    for e in row["scores"]:
        row[e["type"]] = e["score"]
    return row


with open('/content/students.json', 'r') as file:
    data = [json.loads(line.rstrip()) for line in file]

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = df.apply(separate_column, axis=1)
df = df.drop(['scores'], axis=1)

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried many ways but every time I keep getting this error, for the code you save suggested the result is same: https://ibb.co/2W06RKB

Comment: My bad. I forgot to import json module in the code provided. The code above has been corrected. If this does not help perhaps the problem is in the json file you are working with.

Comment: @AkashKumar, I think I get it what your issue is all about. Using single quotes for keys are not allowed in JSON. You need to use double quotes.

Comment: I still get the same error. Yes, I also think so, I am using this file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Akashkunwar/Guvi-assignment/main/Files%20of%20Student%20Database/students.json

Comment: I see. The file you are using is not a valid json. It is just a text file with multiple dicts.

Comment: @AkashKumar, the code above is updated to handle your data.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But, the code you have updated converted dataframe in 1 row and 342 column. like this: https://ibb.co/9wv043F But, I want data is this format where data in score columns are  organized manner like column name Exam, Quiz, and Homework: https://ibb.co/wMfFvWR

Comment: @AkashKumar, Code has been updated. The result of the code is on the image attached.